# how to implement a quoted printable decoder into reading the body of an email?

Tags: mongodb, go

The following code (partial of the full code), creates a reader, then read the body of an email and store them into 'final body'. this final body is then passed into mongoldb for archiving. However, the message body that is read is quoted printable, and I want the body passed into mongodb to be decoded into utf8. how to implement quoted printable package into this code, and where exactly?

```
// Creates a reader.

    mediaType, params, err := mime.ParseMediaType(contentType)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Unable to read the type of the content.")
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    reader := multipart.NewReader(msg.Body, params["boundary"])

    // Reads the body
    finalBody := ""
    if strings.HasPrefix(mediaType, "multipart/") {
        for {
            p, err := reader.NextPart()
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                return
            }
            slurp, err := ioutil.ReadAll(p)
            if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
                return
            }
            finalBody += string(slurp)
        }
    } else {
        txt, err := ioutil.ReadAll(msg.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        finalBody += string(txt)
    }
```

and this segment passed the final body into mongodb

```
importMsg := &importer.Mail{
        Body: finalBody }

    // Saves in MongoDB
    dal := importer.NewMailDAO(c, mongo)
    dal.Save(importMsg)

}
```

Comment: Separate from the encoding issue, you probably don't want to concatenate multipart alternatives. You should select the alternative you consider "best" for your application.

Comment: what is the reason for such assessment? would you please explain? I am still learning

Comment: If the message has plain text and html parts, you probably want to pick the part you consider best instead of concatenating them.

Comment: I see...  thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [quotedprintable](https://godoc.org/mime/quotedprintable) package. When the encoding of a body element is quotedprintable, slurp up the text with:

```
slurp, err := ioutil.ReadAll(quotedprintable.NewReader(r))
```

where `r` is either the body or a part.